# MS Access 2003: User was able to enter an invalid value; how?

Tags: ms-access

I have a strange phenomen I can't explain nor reproduce and I'm hoping you have an idea how it was possible for the user to enter an invalid value.

I have an Access-MDB with a form containing an edit field that should only accept time values without any date-information.

The relevant properties of that edit field are as below:

- bound to a Date/Time database value (since access know no time-only datatype)
- Format: "Time, 24hrs"
- Input Format: "99:99"

(I use the german version of Access, so the property names may be a little different, but you see the pattern)

Now I found out that a user was able to enter a date value into that field. I'm nearly 100% sure that it was an accident and no "clever hack" in the form of directly opening the table and editing the corresponding Date/Time field. Since the entry was made back in 2009 (nobody spotted the error), I have no chance to ask the user how it was done.

I found two wrong entries with the dates "01.06.2000" and "01.07.2000" and I guess the user wanted to enter the times "06:00" and "07:00".

I tried every input I can imagine (like "6.0", "6;0", "6,0", copy&paste) but I was unable to trick access and enter anything except digits and the colon.

Do you have any idea what is going on and how the user was able to enter these dates accidentially?

Comment: The easiest way to address this is to instead use an unbound control and use its BeforeUpdate field to verify what's entered, and then use the AfterUpdate event to write to the underlying field.

Answer (score 1):

A Jet/ACE Date/Time value is never stored "without any date information". If you attempt to store only the time component, it will actually be stored with the same time on day zero (Dec 30, 1899).

We can only speculate how the incorrect data was added back in 2009.  If you want the database engine to require your Date/Time values to be stored with day zero as the date component, you can add a table-level validation rule.  From the table property sheet, try this for Validation Rule:

```
DateValue([your_date_field])=CDate("1899/12/30")
```

If you want to allow Null for your_date_field, try this version:

```
IsNull([your_date_field]) Or DateValue([your_date_field])=CDate("1899/12/30")
```

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities:

- A developer (you?) did it by accident when looking at the raw table
- The client Access software went momentarily crazy and corrupted the entry.  This has happen to us (fortunately very rarely) where our Access tables will end up with non-ASCII characters in a string field.
- A bug in Access runtime allowed the problem in the past, but has been corrected in a service pack.

Finally, if you put in 90 hours, does it overflow into 4 days and something?  That might do it.